# How to configure apache with public ip

Tags: networking, 20.04, apache2, webserver

I have tried lot of things to configure apache2 with my public ip address but still now I am unable to do it successfully. Can anyone help me?

**What I tried already?**

I installed apache2 and its working perfectly. I can access the server through my other computers which is connected in the same lan.

I configured my router and forwarded apache2 port to my local ip but still its not working. I can't access my server on public network.

Somewhere I hear that some ISP block connection to **port 80** so I changed my apache2 port to **8080**. Again it doesn't work. I tried **port 99** also, same thing happen. I checked my server after changing port via lan computers its working perfectly but when I try to connect by my public ip it doesn't work.

Don't know what I am missing in the process or my ISP block every port? Then how to check if **my ISP blocking it or not?**

Comment: Some ISPs block a lot of ports for people on residential plans. One tool that might be useful is [canyouseeme.org](https://canyouseeme.org), which will let you test ports. Be sure to have the necessary ports on the router forwarded correctly (or just put the Apache machine in the DMZ temporarily) and use the website from that computer to see which ports you might be able to use. Generally anything under 1000 will be blocked by many ISPs.

Comment: What a co-incident, I always check my ports from canyouseeme.org but it's showing error to every port I tried. If my ISP blocking it, do you know any way to check if my ISP blocking it or not?

Comment: The easiest way to know for sure if it's the ISP would be to call the company and ask them. Alternatively, you would need to connect your Apache machine directly to the modem, ensure the IP is in the DMZ for the modem, then test. This will let you know whether the problem is the ISP or something on your local network. If you still cannot connect when plugged directly into the router, then your ISP is the problem.

Comment: Talking about DMZ, My router don't have this feature and I turned off router firewall completely to check if it is working or not. It's not working. So can you tell me am I missing some setting or everything is fine because I can access from local network?

Comment: Comments are not really designed for "chat", so I'll try to keep this short. You've already confirmed that Apache can be accessed from other devices on your home network, so the problem is not the Apache server. Even if Apache were configured to respond to `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` values that are not the connecting domain/IP, then it would return *something*. If your connection is timing out or CanYouSeeMe cannot connect, then the issue must be the ISP.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I should call my ISP.